# Custom endpoint path for AWS API Gateway WebSocket

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have created an API Gateway with Websocket protocol.
After I deploy the API, I get a WebSocket URL and a connection URL.

e.g.

WebSocket URL: `wss://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test`

Connection URL: `https://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/@connections`

Now everything is fine, I am able to connect to the API, and send and receive messages.
But when I try to access a different path, I get an HTTP 403 error.

e.g. If I try to connect to `wss://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/some/path`
, I get 403 error.

Is it possible to configure API gateway in such a way that it accepts connections to all paths and passes on the path, i.e. `/some/path` in my case, to the `$connect` route handler?

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet supported by AWS. See the article and comments here https://medium.com/@lancers/using-parameter-mapping-in-websocket-api-67b414376d5e

There is a workaround with using an additional server, author of the article proposes the following:
you may put your own server that accepts an URI with path parameters, then return 302 to redirect the client to the WebSocket API endpoint with query string instead.